# How ember data (store) generates ID

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How exactly ID build? Data stored in store by ID, but how the ID is generated?

//Code just to pass requirements

```
normalize(model, hash, prop) {
    hash.id = 'someId';
    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ask about new records ( which creates on client side ) :

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.5.3/addon/-private/system/store.js#L329

```
  /**
    If possible, this method asks the adapter to generate an ID for
    a newly created record.
    @method _generateId
    @private
    @param {String} modelName
    @param {Object} properties from the new record
    @return {String} if the adapter can generate one, an ID
  */
  _generateId(modelName, properties) {
    var adapter = this.adapterFor(modelName);

    if (adapter && adapter.generateIdForRecord) {
      return adapter.generateIdForRecord(this, modelName, properties);
    }

    return null;
  },
```

Also check documentation for  **generateIdForRecord** http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_generateIdForRecord